# SQL Server : Select Record Where ID Appears In String

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of items and need to select the rows where the item ID is found inside a string formed and retrieved from elsewhere. For example the string to match looks like:

```
'100684','103223','103228'
```

or I can strip it to produce:

```
100684,103223,103228
```

But I am not getting any success from the following attempts:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table Where ID LIKE '" & strString & "'  "
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table Where ID IN '" & strString & "'  "
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table Where PATINDEX('%" & ID & "%','" & strString & "') > 0 "
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table Where PATINDEX(ID,'" & strString & "') > 0 "
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table Where CHARINDEX(ID, '" & strString & "') > 0 "
```

These either fail to produce a result or give an error like

> *Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function*

Comment: I like SQL injections. When are people going to learn that this is a no no...

Comment: No chance of injection when the string is collated by a function reading from other tables.

Comment: You still have plan cache bloat and excess compilations.  Each distinct string passed into sql server will be compiled and cached, even if it's only used once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use stripped version of your string and try

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table Where ID IN (" & strString & ")"
```

Comment: NO, Please Don't Do This! This is a horrible coding practice.  This is the kind of code that create SQL injection vulnerabilities.  And even if you appropriately validate strString, it's still poor coding practice as you'll cause un-necessary compilations and plan cache bloat.

Comment: My code was missing the brackets. It worked with both stripped and unstripped string.

Comment: ID in ( '234', '2345') only works because of implicit conversion from string to int.  Implicit conversions can place limits on the plans that sql server can generate for a query, which may cause performance problems.

Comment: There was no other way to do this task. The IDs are all 6 digit numbers so there is no duplication.

Answer (score 1):

A conversion from STRING to INT will help

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table Where ID = CONVERT(INT,'"&strString &"')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good rule of thumb:  Strings passed in as parameters should NEVER be concatenated into the SQL query text.

The correct approach is to use either named parameters, or a table valued parameter.
You want to end up with a sql query like this:

```
 SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table Where id IN (@p1, @p2, @p3)"
```

which you then call passing in the appropriate values for @p1, @p2, @p3.  It's fine to dynamically build the string with varying numbers of @p's.

If you've got more than 2100 values to pass in then you should use a table valued parameter.

Lastly, you can also safely parse strings in T-SQL using a splitter.
Jeff Moden has an excellent article on SSC about splitting text efficiently: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/